# 2 Analytics codes in same website

Tags: google-analytics

I recently noticed that my wordpress website has 2 analytics code. One of them is inserted by the theme itself and I am not able to remove that code from 'head', as its coming from some script.

I can not see the metrics in my GA account, probably because only one code works per website. (not sure)

Is there any solution around this?

Answer (score 0):

It can cause some problems if you have more than one "full" Analytics Code on your page. (problems with Bounce Rates, Timings, ...).

Where are two solutions for this (if you can´t get rid of the GA-Code from the Theme)

1. Manipulate the GA Tracking Code

This could look like this:

```
if (!window.ga) { (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); } ga('create', '{{YOUR_UA-ID}}', 'auto', 'tracking'); ga('tracking.send', 'pageview');
```

2. Install Google Tag Manager and implement your GA-tracking through the GTM.
   Tracking through GTM works slightly different, as normal GA-Tracking. So you won´t get tracking problems.

I would recommend the GTM solution

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with this code (replace UA-XXXXXXXX-X with your tracking code)

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)
  {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
 })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto', ‘xyz’);
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga(‘xyz.send’, ‘pageview’);

</script>
```